# Is it possible to can lemons in a simple syrup as opposed to using salt?

Tags: food-preservation, lemon

I would like to know if its possible to can/preserve whole meyer lemons in a sweet simple syrup, much like you would can peaches or cherries.

I haven't been able to find a recipe for canning lemons that isn't savory and doesn't use salt, but I want to use these lemons for baking so the whole salt canning method isn't going to work. I'm down to the last of my precious meyer lemons for this summer and really want to preserve them so that I'm able to whip up a cheesecake or what have you any time of the year using preserved sweet lemons.

If anyone has had success with this and wants to share their experience i would appreciate it.

Comment: While it is not what you have asked, have you considered freezing the zest?  That can be very effective.  Please note that recipe requests are off topic here at SA, but specific questions about technique or how to be successful are most welcome.   For canning, you should only accept recipes from a reputable source such as a University Extension center. You want to be extremely careful with safety issues related to home canning.

Comment: Perhaps "lemon conserve" or "lemon marmalade" would be a better starting point for your search for sweet preserved lemons.

Answer (score 5):

You can bottle (can) citrus fruit including lemons, but they tend to end up like marmalade

If you want to preserve their current flavour, I would suggest freezing thin slices on a metal tray, and when frozen transfer them to small airtight containers or strong 'zipped' freezer bags

Alternatively you can freeze strips of zest (use a potato peeler) and the juice as ice blocks (small size). Again, store in small airtight containers or strong 'zipped' freezer bags